# generate a unique url for a web application

Tags: url

I'm building a Python Flask web application that performs an analysis based on the inputs a user enters. I want to allow the user to send this analysis to their Facebook friends as a link; therefore, I need the analysis page to have a *unique* URL for every instance.

My approach up to this point has been to build the analysis page URL like so:

```
website.com/results/<Facebook ID>/<time in seconds since the epoch>
```

I'm using `time.time()` for the last parameter and the analysis data (paired with the FB ID and time) is stored in a database. An example URL might look something like this:

```
website.com/results/1619598720181063/1508036889
```

Does this approach seem feasible, are there best practices for generating a persistent unique URL, or is there a much better approach I'm overlooking?

Note I'm using Facebook's [Send Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog) to share the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider letting the database handle it for you by using an auto-generated unique key for the data. Key are guaranteed unique and your URI could be even simpler: results/123

Comment: Excellent idea! So for SQLite I could use the primary key and for MongoDB I could use the ObjectId, correct?

Comment: Sure. Whatever DB you use will have a reliable unique key.